# sql server getting total for each group

Tags: sql-server, group-by

Not sure how to go about this:-

I have a query

`select name, city, salary from Employee`

I can get a sum by doing a grouping

`select name, city, sum(salary) total_salary from Employee group by name, city`

How can I get the total per city as a separate row under each city ?

Expected Sample Result:

```
Name City Salary
n1   c1   10
n2   c1   20
T1   c1   30
n3   c2   20
n4   c2   50
T2   c2   70
```

Comment: Are you just looking for a cumulative sum? That seems to be what you want, based off the example output.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use [`GROUP BY` with the `GROUPING SETS ()` modifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-group-by-transact-sql):

```
select name, city, sum(salary) total_salary 
from Employee 
group by grouping sets ((city, name), (city)) ;
```

Example of use from Microsoft Technet: [Using `GROUP BY` with `ROLLUP`, `CUBE`, and `GROUPING SETS`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522495(v=sql.105).aspx)

Answer (score 12):

`WITH ROLLUP` would come close to what you want:

```
select name, city, sum(salary) total_salary
  from Employee
 group by city, name WITH ROLLUP
```

This would give you:

```
Name City Salary
n1   c1   10
n2   c1   20
NULL c1   30
n1   c2   20
n2   c2   50
NULL c2   70
NULL NULL 100
```

If you don't want the NULLs, you can replace them. The `GROUPING` function tells you when a column is NULL because of the `ROLLUP`;

```
select CASE WHEN GROUPING(city) = 1 THEN 'Grand'
            WHEN GROUPING(name) = 1 THEN 'Total'
            ELSE name END as name
      ,CASE WHEN GROUPING(city) = 1 THEN 'Total'
            ELSE city END as city
      ,sum(salary) total_salary
  from Employee
 group by city, name WITH ROLLUP
```

See the results in this [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/b82762/3)